# I get a invalid route on my server when i try stripe connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

so i followed this tutorial: http://www.munocreative.com/nerd-notes/winvoice
also this:https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect

and when i skip the form, i get sent to my uri that i have set in my connect settings but i get this:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/auth/stripe_connect/callback"
```

this is my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'index#home'
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
end
```

this is my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def stripe_connect
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes({
      provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
      uid: request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
      access_code: request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token,
      publishable_key: request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.stripe_publishable_key
    })
      # anything else you need to do in response..
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Stripe") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.stripe_connect_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

any other details you need me to give, just ask. Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted your server since the changes?

Comment: Yeah i restarted it many times.